# How can I make a Stored procedure return a bit value?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure similar to this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_mark_question]
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT  1 AS Authenticated,
           0 AS RC
END
```

It is executed like this:

```
var rc = await db.Database.SqlQuery<AnswerToClient>(sql).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

public class AnswerToClient
{
    public bool Authenticated { get; set; }
    public bool RC { get; set; }
}
```

I get an error:

> The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int32' type to the 'System.Boolean' type is not valid.

I think this might be because the stored procedure returns a number. How can I make it return a value that can be converted to the bool?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CAST(1 AS BIT) AS Authenticated
```